# Why doesn't Cache::clear() clear my (view) cache? (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, caching

Even though it's [documented](http://book.cakephp.org/view/348/Clearing-the-Cache) that CakePHP will automatically clear the view caches when a model is updated, it doesn't.

> It is important to remember that Cake will clear a cached view if a model used in the cached view is modified. For example, if a cached view uses data from the Post model, and there has been an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE query made to a Post, the cache for that view is cleared, and new content is generated on the next request.

Even calling the suggested `Cache::clear()` method manually does nothing. How do I clear the view cache in Cake?

*(As of version `1.2.2.8120`. Looking at the repository commits, even .8256 should have this problem.)*

Comment: possibly related to this, i was plagued by client-side caching in my baked index views. firefox, safari, IE were all problems, chrome was not. i fixed it by calling $this->disableCache() in my controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `clearCache()`, possibly automatically in a model `afterSave` callback:

```
// model file:
function afterSave($created) {
    clearCache();
}
```

*(Please also document other available solutions, this is the only one I could find.)*

Comment: shouldn't you also use `parent::afterSave(false);` as Aziz suggested in the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

use `Cache::clearCache();`, or use `Cache::delete();` to delete only the exact file you no longer want.

```
function afterSave($created) {
    parent::afterSave(false);
    Cache::delete('left_menu_eng');
}
```

Comment: what does it mean "delete exactly file you don't want to delete"?